# I2C protocole to LCD's microcontroller

Tags: vhdl

I'm looking to design a VHLD architecture to communicate between a FPGA to a LCD screen. The LCD screen uses a microcontroller to read and write data on the I2C protocol. However, the LCD screen itself does not read I2C and requieres to be send 10 bits of data at a time (hence the use of the microcontroller) as shown on the image right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwMHQ.png) .

My problem is that I am not exactly sure how to send the 10 bits of data. Understand me, I know how to make a Master/Slave I2C protocole on VHDL and I also know how to make the state machine necessary to write the instructions. The thing is that the I2C protocole can only send 8 bits of data at a time. Consequently, I do not know if I have to send two pack of 8 bits with the last 6 bits useless for exemple, or if I have to send it some other ways.

The LCD screen I am currently using is the LCD2004a and the I2C microcontroller is PCF8574 if this can help. I am fairly sure the information can be found somewhere on the internet (as the LCD screen seems quite commun), but it would appear that my skills in VHDL are quite new and that I do not know the correct key word to google my problem effectivly.

So to summarize my problem: The I2C protocoles sends X numbers of bits (in pack of 8) in Y orders. It goes in the black box that is the micro-controller and 10 bits gets out of it (RS, RW and DB{7 to 0}). I need to find X and Y.

Thanks in advance!

Sincerly,

Nathaniel

Comment: How were you planning on sending 10 bits via a PCF8574, anyway?  It only has 8 I/O pins!  But you don't actually need that many to talk to a standard text LCD: you can leave DB0-3 unconnected and use 4-bit interface mode, and tie R/W low if you don't need to read data back from the display.  So 6 pins total: DB4-7, RS, and E.

Comment: That does seems fair indeed, I did not realise that the PCF8574 only had 8 I/O pins. And I will use the 4-bit interface mode. However my problem remains the same, I use the 4-bit interface mode to send information to 6 differents pins. I am quite new at using I2C interface... Can you suggest in which order I should send my data from I2C so it is correctly interpreted by the PCF8574?

Comment: The PCF8475 data sheet will tell you exactly what the I2C transaction should look like to control its pins.  Note that you're going to need to write to it 3 times for every 4-bit chunk that goes to the LCD - once with E low, once with E high, once with E low again.  That pulse on E latches the data into the display, and you don't want any of the other pins changing at the same time.

Comment: Alright, I will look into that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1155120, Yes I did figure that out afterward. Thank you very much for your help nonetheless!